# DNSHostNotFound: Failed to look up service "":DNS name does not exist. try

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

> DNSHostNotFound: Failed to look up service "":DNS name does not exist. try 'C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\bin\mongo.exe --help' for more information

I am getting this error while coonecting with Sandbox to mongo shell.

```
PS C:\Users\hp> mongo -version
MongoDB shell version v4.2.7
git version: 51d9fe12b5d19720e72dcd7db0f2f17dd9a19212
allocator: tcmalloc
modules: enterprise
build environment:
    distmod: windows-64
    distarch: x86_64
    target_arch: x86_64
```

What is the error? I am not able to understand.

Answer (score 3):

DNS using Spectrum blocks srv requests to MongoDB Atlas.   I had to change my DNS servers to Google's 8.8.8.8

Answer (score 1):

guessing from the kind of question it seems that you were taking mongoDB university course M001. I too, was taking that course and have faced a similar problem. The solution is to remove the password part from the string or command. The following snippet will help to understand this.

Instead of the command-

```
mongo "mongodb+srv://sandbox-jbc3i.mongodb.net/test" --username m001-student --password m001-mongodb-basics
```

Enter-

```
mongo "mongodb+srv://sandbox-jbc3i.mongodb.net/test" --username m001-student
```

After this password authentication will be asked. Now here's a twist, you cannot see the password which you are typing in command prompt or powershell interface. Just type it and then press enter, and you will be connected to the mongoDB atlas. After that, you should see the prompt-

```
MongoDB Enterprise Sandbox-shard-0:PRIMARY>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I am writing this answer after researching on many websites and even contacted MongoDB support.

The problem is regarding the DNS server of your wifi. Kindly change your wifi or use the mobile hotspot and also whitelist the current connected IP on MongoDB, It will surely help, or Change the DNS of your wifi.

Answer (score 0):

Please whitelist your ip first and then use a mobile-hotspot to connect. Modify the databaseuser (by changing its username and password) and then try to connect. It will work.